# Can I Handle Chunk oriented step errors produced in Reader initialization?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a **Chunk-Step** on my Job that have a **JdbcCursorItemReader**. This reader have a SQL Query and I want handle any error that can this SQL produce to skip this step completing the JOB (like a decider's behavior)

An example of this error could be some COLUMN identifier be modified, permissions or visibility over a table, etc ...

I tried with **ItemReadListener** and **SkipPolicy.shouldSkip** without success. Any help?

**Step Defintion**:

```
<batch:step id="manageWFStep" next="endTaskletStep">
    <batch:tasklet>
        <batch:chunk
            commit-interval="1"
            reader  ="manageWFReader" 
            processor="manageWFProcessor" 
            writer  ="manageWFWriter"
            skip-policy="skipPolicyError">
            <batch:listeners>
                <batch:listener ref="workFlowReadListener"></batch:listener>
            </batch:listeners>
        </batch:chunk>
    </batch:tasklet>
</batch:step>
```

**ItemReadListener**:

```
@Component
public class WorkFlowReadListener implements ItemReadListener<WorkFlowDTO> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(WorkFlowReadListener.class);

    @Override
    public void afterRead(WorkFlowDTO dto) { 
        logger.debug("[AfterRead] WF Leido"); 
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeRead() { }

    @Override
    public void onReadError(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Se ha producido un error en la lectura del objeto. ", e);

    }

}
```

**My Reader**:

```
<bean id="manageWFReader" class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="daoDataSource" />
        <property name="rowMapper">
            <bean class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper">
                <property name="mappedClass" value="com.myproject.WorkFlowDTO" />
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="sql">
            <value>
                <![CDATA[ *Any Wrong SQL ]]>
            </value>
        </property>               
    </bean>
```

**SkipPolicyError**:

```
@Component
public class SkipPolicyError implements SkipPolicy {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SkipPolicyError.class);

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable exc, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
        logger.error("[SkipPolicyError:shouldSkip] Error desconocido al procesar el registro", exc);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Example of the fatal error:

```
20200213 14:16:06.857 INFO   org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler [[ # ]] - Executing step: [manageWFStep]
20200213 14:16:07.397 INFO   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader [[ # ]] - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [org/springframework/jdbc/support/sql-error-codes.xml]
20200213 14:16:07.422 INFO   org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodesFactory [[ # ]] - SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase, Hana]
20200213 14:16:07.613 ERROR  org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep [[ # ]] - Encountered an error executing step manageWFStep in job ComposerDigitalDocumentsJob
org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Failed to initialize the reader
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support.AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.open(AbstractItemCountingItemStreamItemReader.java:147)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, the cause of `Failed to initialize the reader` is not shown (it could be that your db is not up and running, or you have an error in your sql query, etc). For reader initialization, I would fail fast because it is likely to be a configuration issue or a resource problem.

Comment: Yes, in this case I manually provoke the error with a bad SQL, but I want prepare this reader to avoid this type of errors in a future if the table or some columns change their name or get deleted. I will edit this post in a minutes with the full stack trace. Thanks